# How to click on label element text

Tags: java, html, webdriver

My code is like this..

```
<ul class="sb_dropdown" style="display: none;">
 <li id="sb_up_arrow" class="uiebatesca"/>
  <li>
  <label data-search-for="all">
    <strong>All</strong>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li style="background-color: transparent;">
   <label data-search-for="Automotive">Stores</label>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label data-search-for="Beauty">Deals</label>
  </li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

Now i want to select `Stores` by using webdriver with java.
I tried by using:

```
List<WebElement> elementsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='ui_element']/ul/li"));
Select ddvalues=new Select(elementsList.get(1)); 
ddvalues.selectByIndex(1);
```

But this is not working...

Is there any alternate ways to select this `Stores`.

I tried to focus move to the "Stores" label, with this code...

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);      
builder.moveToElement(elementsList.get(i)).perform();
elementsList.get(i).click();
```

but this is also not working...

Comment: Two things: Firstly, can you show us your whole code? For example, the value of that string variable `element` is crucial, but you haven't shown us what value it has. Secondly, can you describe in detail (including errors if relevant) what is "not working"?

Comment: List<WebElement> elementsList =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='ui_element']/ul/li"));

Select ddvalues=new Select(elementsList.get(1));
ddvalues.selectByIndex(1);

this is my code...

Comment: It's best to edit your question to include the new information; it's a lot more readable that way.

Comment: Error i am getting is :: Element should have been "select" but was "li"

Comment: You'll get that error as you're attempting to use a method from the `Select` class that ONLY works with `Select` style elements, ie it has the `<select>` tag.

Comment: Hi @Mark Rowlands,
Thanks for your reply, yes i  understood why the error is coming. And may i know how to select the "Stores" text, which is in <li> tag..

Comment: When you say select it, do you mean to click on it, put it into focus to do something else with it or... ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "select", you need to click on the "Stores" label.  As others have pointed out, selecting an item using a `new Select()` will not work, because its expecting the element to be a  element.

You can "select" the "Stores" label by using:

```
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Stores'])"));
element.click();
```